# StackOverflowError caused by non-static member of same type

Tags: java, exception, stack-overflow

The code in the following snippet throws `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

```
public class Main
{
    private Main m=new Main("");  //This statement causes the exception.

    private Main(String s)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Main m1=new Main("The constructor called.");
            System.out.println("Successful!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

There is no meaning to deliberately write this statement `private Main m=new Main("");` inside the class itself but that statement is not ever supposed to be used by any code in the class then how can that statement cause the exception to be thrown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time you call the constructor, you create an instance and thus execute the initializing code

```
private Main m=new Main("");
```

which calls the constructor, etc.

You probably want

```
private static Main m=new Main("");
```

in order to keep a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely normal that your program cause a stack overflow ...
The compiler does not check that your member m is used or not in your code, though you are right it could have done it, probably with side effects : object not been built ...
In order to construct a Main object  another Main object (the private Main m member) has to be constructed ... which gives an infinite recursion, hence the stack oveflow

Comment: "*The chicken comes first before the egg.*" - ha ha.